# After Restoring my code from a backup, I am getting a force close again, and cannot figure out what's wrong

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, forceclose

I lost all of my code when my laptop died. No hope of recovery. After reconstructing my app from a backup, I get nothing but force close, with no errors. I tried researching, and reading the log.

Logcat:

```
10-05 04:01:09.858: W/dalvikvm(4257): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d560)
10-05 04:01:09.858: E/AndroidRuntime(4257): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-05 04:01:09.858: E/AndroidRuntime(4257): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hyperspacemg.showstopper/com.hyperspacemg.showstopper.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-05 04:01:09.858: E/AndroidRuntime(4257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
10-05 04:01:09.858: E/AndroidRuntime(4257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
10-05 04:01:09.858: E/AndroidRuntime(4257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
10-05 04:01:09.858: E/AndroidRuntime(4257):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
10-05 04:01:09.858: E/AndroidRuntime(4257):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-05 04:01:09.858: E/AndroidRuntime(4257):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-05 04:01:09.858: E/AndroidRuntime(4257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
10-05 04:01:09.858: E/AndroidRuntime(4257):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-05 04:01:09.858: E/AndroidRuntime(4257):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-05 04:01:09.858: E/AndroidRuntime(4257):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
10-05 04:01:09.858: E/AndroidRuntime(4257):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
10-05 04:01:09.858: E/AndroidRuntime(4257):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-05 04:01:09.858: E/AndroidRuntime(4257): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-05 04:01:09.858: E/AndroidRuntime(4257):     at com.hyperspacemg.showstopper.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:131)
10-05 04:01:09.858: E/AndroidRuntime(4257):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-05 04:01:09.858: E/AndroidRuntime(4257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
10-05 04:01:09.858: E/AndroidRuntime(4257):     ... 11 more
```

If you need my code let me know, StackOverflow says I have too much code to post...

Comment: Post the code there is no way to debug Null Pointer without code

Comment: Can you please post your code ? And also let us know which code is on MainActivity.java:131 line number ?

Comment: Did you restore **ALL** your code **AND** all required libraries? Your code line 131 or just before it should show what actually fails to load.

Comment: post the code for that Nullpointer exception in onCreate()

Comment: I don't have enough rep to post more than two links, so:
Here is ALL of my java: http://pastebin.com/V9WNNeDv
Here is ALL of my xml: http://pastebin.com/NCiLgGeX

Comment: Did you guys forget about me?

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint at line 131 and ensured that valueSens is not null? Are you intending to actually set the text to sbar_sens_position or sbar_red_position? Are they null? Something on line 131 is...

Comment: breakpoint? I fixed the bar position text. the Value (actually entire block) near 131, I deleted just now, as I had removed that seekbar from the gui. Still force close

Comment: So now you've removed the block at 131 can you post the new LogCat and update the code links to pastebin. You definitely need to google your IDE (Eclipse?) and debugging...  have a read around the keywords eclipse+debug+breakpoint+android

Comment: MainActivity.java http://pastebin.com/RP9jyPKD
Logcat http://pastebin.com/fkGnLviD
Yes, Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was still code that had been removed from the GUI, but was left in the activity. Removing all code related to the Null value "side" (I had missed some at line 284) fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

Please close other projects and clean the projects.This will solve it.

Comment: This is a fresh windows install, and the only only project in existence on a fresh eclipse, sdk, adt install.